# Factors that contribute to XGBoost slower training time on SageMaker distributed vs single-instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, machine-learning, xgboost, amazon-sagemaker

I want to create a module on distributed training to fulfill the customer's request. I'm editing [this notebook](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/machine-learning/associating-prediction-results-with-input-data-using-amazon-sagemaker-batch-transform/) by adding a few lines of code (below) to run the training using `FullyReplicated` and `SharedByS3Key` with two instances for training to show how the customer can use distributed training with XGBoost.

I successfully run all three training types -- single, distributed:sharedbys3key, and distributed:fullyreplicated. However, the training time for the single took 3 minutes, whereas the distributed both took longer (6 & 7 minutes, respectively).

Why would the distributed training in this case be slower? The training data is only 500 records. Does the small sample size affect training size and the smaller size would actually make distributed training slower? Would it be faster if the training set was significantly larger?

I'm using the same hyperparameters for all training types, and everything else is the same. The only difference between the jobs are the instance count (1 versus 2), and the `S3DataDistributionType` for the two distributed training methods.

Comment: You can see from the logs the actual execution time and discriminate whether it takes time for instance provisioning rather than communication overhead.

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming with 500 records you are dealing with one file in the training data . The SharedByS3Key shines if you have multiple files in the training data because it will allocate each file to one training instance .With such small data set I think the overhead to spin multiple instances and move data across those instances is the only thing that comes to mind that will take up time.